# Calling exit doesn't work as expected

Tags: bash

I need to run several child processes in background and pipe data between them. When the script exits, I want to kill any remaining of them, so I added

```
trap cleanup EXIT

cleanup()
{
    echo "Cleaning up!"
    pkill -TERM -P $$
}
```

Since I need to react if one of the processes reports an error, I created wrapper functions. Anything that ends with `fd` is a previously opened file descriptor, connected to a FIFO pipe.

```
run_gui()
{
    "$GAME_BIN" $args <&$gui_infd >&$gui_outfd # redirecting IO to some file descriptors
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
        echo exiting ok
        exit $OK_EXITCODE
    else
        exit $ERROR_EXITCODE
    fi
}
```

The functions `run_ai1(), run_ai2` are analogous.

```
run_ai1()
{
    "$ai1" <&$ai1_infd >&$ai1_outfd
    if [[ $? == 0 || $? == 1 || $? == 2 ]]; then
        exit $OK_EXITCODE
    else
        exit $ERROR_EXITCODE
    fi
}

run_ai2()
{
    "$ai2" <&$ai2_infd >&$ai2_outfd
    if [[ $? == 0 || $? == 1 || $? == 2 ]]; then
        exit $OK_EXITCODE
    else
        exit $ERROR_EXITCODE
    fi
}
```

Then I run the functions and do the needed piping

```
printinit 1 >&$ai1_infd
printinit 2 >&$ai2_infd
run_gui &
run_ai1 &
run_ai2 &
while true; do
    echo "Started the loop"
    while true; do
        read -u $ai1_outfd line || echo "Nothing read"
        echo $line
        if [[ $line ]]; then
            echo "$line" >&$gui_infd
            echo "$line" >&$ai2_infd
            if [[ "$line" == "END_TURN" ]]; then
                break
            fi
        fi
    done
    sleep $turndelay
    while true; do
        read -u $ai2_outfd line || echo "nothing read"
        echo $line
        if [[ $line ]]; then
            echo "$line" >&$gui_infd
            echo "$line" >&$ai1_infd
            if [[ "$line" == "END_TURN" ]]; then
                break
            fi
        fi
    done
    sleep $turndelay
done
```

When `$GAME_BIN` exits, i.e. the GUI is closed by the close button, I can see the `exiting ok` message on the stdout, but the `cleanup` function is not called at all. When I add a manual call to `cleanup` before calling `exit $OK_EXITCODE`, although the processes are killed:

```
./game.sh: line 309:  9193 Terminated              run_gui
./game.sh: line 309:  9194 Terminated              run_ai1
./game.sh: line 309:  9195 Terminated              run_ai2
./game.sh: line 309:  9203 Terminated              sleep $turndelay
```

the loop runs anyway and the script doesn't exit, as it should (`exit $OK_EXITCODE`). The AI scripts are simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    echo END_TURN
done
```

There is no `wait` call anywhere in my script. What am I doing wrong?

What's interesting: when I call `jobs -p` right after `run_ai2 &`, then I get 3 pids listed. On the other hand, when I invoke this command from the `cleanup` function - the output is empty.

Besides, why is the `sleep $turndelay` process terminated? It's not a child invoked process.

Comment: Are the ai processes still your children? (i.e. Do they fork themselves to detach or anything like that?) What does the process tree look like when things are running?

Comment: No, I'm not doing anything else than what's pasted in here.

Comment: Don't limit the ps output to the tty. That's going to miss detached processes. Try `ps faxww` and see what the tree for your script looks like. I bet you find the ai processes somewhere *else* because they are detaching themselves.

Comment: @EtanReisner I used a wrong script (I have two in my working directory) which explains the missing processes. I updated the description of the problem.

Comment: Where is the `trap` set up in the toplevel script? Traps don't get inherited by sub-shells by default. And children of the parent shell aren't visible to the sub-shell. You need to run `cleanup` in the *parent* shell when `run_gui` exits.

Comment: @EtanReisner You can make this an answer (that it doesn't work as expected because of being run in a subshell). Now I don't know how to solve it properly - but I'll make a separate question for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `EXIT` trap fires when the trapping script exits. Your toplevel script isn't exiting here.

The `trap` isn't inherited by the sub-shell that your `run_*` functions are running under (from being run in the background) so it never triggers when the sub-shell's exit.

What you want is most likely what you did manually (though slightly incorrectly it sounded like).

You want the `cleanup` function called from `run_gui` when `$GAME` has exited. Something like this.

```
run_gui() {
    "$GAME_BIN" $args <&$gui_infd >&$gui_outfd # redirecting IO to some file descriptors
    ret=$?
    cleanup
    exit $ret
}
```

Then you'll just need to make sure that `cleanup` gets the right value of `$$` (Which in `bash` it will, for your usage, even in a sub-shell since `$$` in a sub-shell is the parent process ID but you might want to make that more explicit by setting up a handler in your main script for a signal and signalling the main script when `run_gui` terminates instead.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you are getting some child processes kicked off by a child process.  Do this: in another window do a `ps -ft pts/1` or whatever your tty is.  Verify.

Also change the pkill to a `kill $(jobs -p)` and see if that works.

Comment: I used a wrong script (I have two in my working directory) which explains the missing processes. I updated the description of the problem.